# Can I use characters and/or using puppeter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

As I don't know programming as well and I know you can do it differently (you can help how) then please help me if I can use the characters in this code OR (|| or &&) in some way ?

I would like the results for several selectors to be displayed in one line.

When I do this I have the results but they return to me separately for X and Y
and I'd like a result:
x1 - y1 , x2 - y2, etc.

```
const x = await page.$$eval('.classxxx', options => options.map(option => option.textContent));
const y = await page.$$eval('.classsyyyy', options => options.map(option => option.textContent));
     
console.log(x); // x1, x2, x3 
console.log(y); // y1, y2, y3
```

I'd like the results to be shown next to each other to the next section
That is

```
console log(xy); // x1 y1, x2 y2, x3 y3
```

I've been thinking about something like that but it doesn't work:

```
const y = await page.$$eval('.classsyyyy || .classxxx', options => options.map(option => option.textContent));
```

Comment: I suggest you read about `&&` and `||` to learn about when they can be used.

Comment: One thing you will need to learn to keep straight is when you are using CSS syntax and when you are using JavaScript syntax. These are two separate languages but are often used together in many ways.

Answer (score 5):

For CSS selectors, you can use a comma as OR operator:

```js
const xy = await page.$$eval(
  '.classsyyyy, .classxxx',
  options => options.map(option => option.textContent)
);
```